# why is there more than 1 ball and how can i fix it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pong

hello i am pretty new to programming with pygame and i have this code:

```
import sys, pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 368))
background = pygame.image.load("background.png")
background.convert()
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

speed = [1, 1]
width = 800
height = 368

ball = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
player1 = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
player1rect = player1.get_rect()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            sys.exit()              

    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    screen.blit(player1, player1rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

but when i run it there comes too many balls it should only be one ball. and there comes more and more balls.

Comment: are you clearing the old image of the ball when you're blitting the new?

Comment: The Best option for you is to use a Class which has a __del__ method

Comment: @KDawG how would a dunder-del method help?

Comment: @FredrikHåård a del method works fine alright for I have used them for projects like this(but a whole lot complex) and if you are to use classes, then user2565140 is going to have to recode the program again unfortunately

Comment: @KDawG I know how a destructor works, but it'll not magically redraw the background; it has nothing to do with the problem OP is having.

Comment: @FredrikHåård +1 for noting this, I've used classes but within them I've used .blit() In a damn complex manner that it's difficult to understand what I've coded back in the day (should've used comments)

Comment: @Fredrik Håård is correct, the OP needs to call `screen.fill((0,0,0))` to clear every loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fredrik Håård](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069044/fredrik-haard) is right about re-drawing the background.

The `screen` acts as an image, and when you call `screen.blit()` you draw over part of that image.  When the `while 1:` loop repeats, your image already has one or more copies of the ball on it, and your current code simply draws another image of the ball onto `screen`.

You can draw the background before you move the ball, thus avoiding adding a new variable to hold the previous ball position.

```
...
while 1:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background, ballrect, ballrect) #redraw background over old ball location
    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    screen.blit(player1, player1rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Alternatively, you can reconstruct the entire `screen` each time, by replacing `screen.blit(background, ballrect, ballrect)` above with `screen.blit(background, (0, 0))`, which ensures that the background is correct for each 'frame', but is significantly slower.

My preferred approach is to note that you can pass `pygame.display.update()` a list of rectangles, which makes the call return much quicker.  Make sure you do an initial, full screen, display update before entering the while loop:

```
...
pygame.display.update()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    old_ballrect = ballrect
    screen.blit(background, old_ballrect, old_ballrect) #redraw background over old ball location
    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]

    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    screen.blit(player1, player1rect)
    pygame.display.update([old_ballrect, ballrect])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not being a pygame expert, I assume you would need to do something like

```
new_ball_rect = ballrect.move(speed)
...
screen.blit(background, ballrect, ballrect) #redraw background over old ball location
screen.blit(ball, new_ball_rect)
```

to re-draw the background over the old ball image.